# Changing display none to block using Javascript and polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

How to change display from `none` to `block` using JavaScript/Polymer.

I tried many things but I can't figure out why it is not working.

My current code:

```html
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<dom-module id="navigatie-element">
  <template>
    <style type="text/css">

    #header {
      height: 50px;
      background-color: #D8434A;
      margin-left: -8px;
      margin-top: -8px;
      margin-bottom: 9px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    }

    #header img {
      margin-top: 2px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      width: 218px;
      height: 46px;
    }

    #navbar {
      background-color: #D8434A;
      width: 214px;
      height: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      margin-left: -8px;
      margin-top: -8px;
    }

    #navbar ul {
      margin-left: -40px;
      margin-top: -33px;
    }

    #navbar ul li {
      display: absolute;
      width: 200px;
      height: 40px;
      margin-top: 6px;
      padding-top: 8px;
    }

    #navbar ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      background-color: white;
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      width: 200;
      background-color: #D8434A;
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 10px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid white;
      border-right: 4px solid orange;
      line-height: 50px;
    }

    #navbar ul li a:hover{
      background-color: #FFFA75;
    }

    #navbar ul li img {
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      margin-bottom: -9px;
    }

    #input-field label{
      position: relative;
      left: 500px;
      top: 100px;
    }
    #input-field paper-input{
      position: relative;
      left: 520px;
      top: 90px;
    }
    #input-field paper-button{
      position: relative;
      left: 550px;
      top: 90px;
    }
    #input-field h1{
      position: relative;
      left: 635px;
      top: 50px;
    }
    #input-field2{
      display: none;
    }
    #input-field2 label{
      position: relative;
      left: 500px;
      top: 100px;
    }
    #input-field2 paper-input{
      position: relative;
      left: 520px;
      top: 90px;
    }
    #input-field2 paper-button{
      position: relative;
      left: 550px;
      top: 90px;
    }

    </style>
    <div id="header">
      <img src="afbeeldingen/header_naam.png">
    </div>
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="bestellen.html"><img src="afbeeldingen/menu_bestellen.png">Bestellen</a></li>
        <li><a href="bestellingen.html"><img src="afbeeldingen/menu_bestellingen.png">Bestellingen</a></li>
        <li><a href="serveren.html"><img src="afbeeldingen/menu_serveren.png">Serveren</a></li>
        <li><a href="afrekenen.html"><img src="afbeeldingen/menu_afrekenen.png">Afrekenen</a></li>
      </u>
    </div>

    <div id="input-field">
      <h1>Afrekenen</h1>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><label>Tafelnummer:</label></td>
          <td><paper-input class="test" label=""></paper-input></td>
          <td><paper-button on-click="bevestigen" raised>Bevestigen</paper-button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div id="input-field2">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><label>Betaalmethode:</label></td>
          <td><paper-button on-click="contant" raised>Contant</paper-button></td>
          <td><paper-button on-click="pin" raised>PIN</paper-button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'navigatie-element',
      bevestigen: function() {
        if (document.getElementById("input-field2").style.display == "block") 
        {
          document.getElementById('input-field2').style.display = 'none';
        }
        else 
        {
          document.getElementById('input-field2').style.display = 'block';
        }
      }
    });
class NavigatieElement extends Polymer.Element{
  static get is() { return 'navigatie-element';}
  }

window.customElements.define(NavigatieElement.is, NavigatieElement);
</script>
```

If I add `alert("test");` for example inside the script tag it's working well, so there is nothing wrong with the button.

The problem is the JavaScript I have added to it.

I want to display the `div` after clicking on `bevestigen`
It should change from `block` to `none`

Comment: Have you checked to see if your `if (document.getElementById("input-field2").style.display == "block") ` condition is evaluating? Maybe try a `console.log("...")` inside the block.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood. It's possible that the display property is not changing to `none` because the if statement may not be evaluating to true. Therefore, executing the else statement and re-setting the property value to `block`. Try checking if that condition evaluates to true.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Well i'm getting an error in the consolo:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at HTMLElement.bevestigen (navigatie-element.html:151)
    at HTMLElement.handler (template-stamp.html:92)

Comment: It's possible that your JavaScript is trying to exectue before the DOM is fully initialised. I'd personally use jQuery and wrap your JS code in a `$(document).ready()`. If you have to use vanilla js, try `window.onload = function() {}`.

Comment: Thanks you TomPlum. I got the solution now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about the concepts of Shadow DOM, for example on the Polymer site, [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/shadow-dom).

The important thing to note here is that you are inside your element called `navigatie-element`, you can't use the `document` as a "scope" to query elements in (or in fact you could, but you would query in the top level document, not inside your element).

From what I understand you are interested in your local shadow DOM, so you could try to replace

```
if (document.getElementById("input-field2").style.display == "block") 
{
  document.getElementById('input-field2').style.display = 'none';
}
else 
{
  document.getElementById('input-field2').style.display = 'block';
}
```

with:

```
if (this.shadowRoot.getElementById("input-field2").style.display == "block") 
{
  this.shadowRoot.getElementById('input-field2').style.display = 'none';
}
else 
{
  this.shadowRoot.getElementById('input-field2').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks !!!!

Comment: @Plox333 you are welcome, I am glad it helps.. good luck with your Polymer "journey" :)